# macOS Catalyst `requestSceneSessionActivation` requires multiwindow adoption

Tags: swift, macos, uikit, mac-catalyst, uiscenedelegate

When trying to open a new window in a macOS Catalyst application, I'm using this enum to describe an instance of `NSUserActivity`:

```swift
enum Activity: String {
  case list
  case settings

  var type: String {
    "com.example.app.\(rawValue)"
  }

  var userActivity: NSUserActivity {
    NSUserActivity(activityType: type)
  }
}
```

Then to open a new window, I use this code in a button tap handler, as described in [this raywenderlich.com tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/5814609-adopting-scenes-in-ipados#toc-anchor-022):

```swift
UIApplication
  .shared
  .requestSceneSessionActivation(
    nil,
    userActivity: Activity.settings.userActivity,
    options: nil,
    errorHandler: nil
  )
```

However, this doesn't work and I always get this error message in the debugger console:

```swift
[Scene] Calling -[UIApplication requestSceneSessionActivation:] requires multiwindow adoption.
```

What does this error message mean and what are possibly missing steps here to make support for multiple windows work in a Catalyst app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What actually worked is setting `UIApplicationSupportsMultipleScenes` key within `UIApplicationSceneManifest` dictionary to `YES` in your `Info.plist`:

```xml
    <key>UIApplicationSceneManifest</key>
    <dict>
        <key>UIApplicationSupportsMultipleScenes</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
```

Or if you prefer Xcode GUI, check out this screenshot:

[image: Info.plist in Xcode with the "Enable Multiple Windows" setting]

Unfortunately, this setting doesn't seem to be documented in [the raywenderlich.com tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/5814609-adopting-scenes-in-ipados) or in any of Apple's guides on Catalyst. It only seems to be documented on [this Developer reference page](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/uiapplicationscenemanifest/uiapplicationsupportsmultiplescenes).